# Rails show page not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I click on show page it is not opening .For example when I click on index page and click on any random user in url it comes **http://localhost:3000/users.6** but the show page doesn't get open.But when I  manually type in url **http://localhost:3000/users/6** then I am able to view my show page.

view page

**<%= link_to "Show",users_path(user) %>**

Comment: Always post the required code to find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relevant code is missing, but it's a common issue.

You must have code similar to

```
<%= link_to user.name, user_path(user.id) %>
```

Change it to

```
<%= link_to user.name, user_path(id: user.id) %>
```

Comment: yes i will actually stackoverflow doesn't allow to accept answer within 15 minutes